# Reproduce button action on tab page

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

On LineDetails form we have tab page [Areas]. Under that tab page is button [Read Areas] . That button is redundant and there is no need for it, as that action which is occurred when clicked on it should be done when tab page [Areas] is opened. 
[image]

```
[Control("Button")]
class ReadCommonAreas
{
void clicked()
{
ContractArea contractArea;
AmountMST sumContractArea;

super();

ContractLine_ds.readCommonAreas(ContractLine);
h1_h2.realValue(ContractLine_ds.h1_h2(ContractLine));
efa.realValue(ContractLine_ds.efa(ContractLine));
bfa.realValue(ContractLine_ds.bfa(ContractLine));
mfa.realValue(ContractLine_ds.mfa(ContractLine));
sumArea.realValue(h1_h2.realValue() + efa.realValue() + bfa.realValue() + mfa.realValue());

while select AreaSelector, sum(RentalValue)
from contractArea
group by AreaSelector
where contractArea.ContractId == Contract.ContractId
&& contractArea.RentalObjectId == ContractLine.RentalObjectId
{
sumContractArea += contractArea.RentalValue;
switch (contractArea.AreaSelector)
{
case AreaSelector::CommonAreaBuilding :
contractAreaBFA.realValue(contractArea.RentalValue);
break;
case AreaSelector::CommonAreaSection :
contractAreaEFA.realValue(contractArea.RentalValue);
break;
case AreaSelector::PrimaryArea, AreaSelector::SecondaryArea :
contractAreaH1_H2.realValue(contractArea.RentalValue);
break;
case AreaSelector::CommonAreaFixed :
contractAreaMFA.realValue(contractArea.RentalValue);
break;
}
}
contractAreaSum.realValue(sumContractArea);
}

}
```

How to adapt this, when is clicked on Areas to show info like when it's clicked on Read Areas ?

And after that, I will remove Read Areas button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the `Read Areas` button `Visible = No` to hide it.

Then on the `Areas` tab page, override the `pageActivated()` method and do `ReadAreas.clicked()`. That way the core code stays in tact.

The thing you should consider is if the user tabs off/on the `Areas` page, every time it will click the `Read Areas` button...not sure if that's a problem or not.

Use event handlers and the like where appropriate. This is just off the top of my head general approach.

Comment: Thank you. It's helped a lot.